# How to print the elements of a struct?

Tags: c, data-structures

I have made this program to save the information about a book but it doesn't print it correctly

```
#include <stdio.h>

enum Color {red, green, blue};

struct Book{
    int pages;
    char* author;
    char* title;
    enum Color color;
};

void getInfo(struct Book book){
    book.pages= 200;
    book.author = "Cervantes";
    book.title= "El Quijote";
    book.color = green;

}

void showInfo(struct Book book){

    printf("pages: %d\n", book.pages);
    printf("author: %s\n", book.author);
    printf("title: %s\n", book.title);

    switch (book.color) {
        case red:
            printf("Color: red\n");
            break;
        case green:
            printf("Color: green\n");
            break;
        case blue:
            printf("Color: blue\n");
            break;
    }
}

int main(){
    struct Book book1;

    getInfo(book1);
    showInfo(book1);

    return 0;
}
```

In principle, the program should save them well, because if I put the print inside the function where the data is saved, they do print correctly. But by modularizing the program, it stops doing it.

Comment: `getInfo` is basically a no-op.  It populates values in a variable that is not returned to the caller.

Comment: book should be a pointer in getInfo

Comment: Try: `void getInfo( struct Book *book) { book->pages = 2000...`  and call it with `getInfo(&book1);`

Comment: you have libro instead of book ... is that your error?

Comment: @WilliamPursell would you mind to write ir correctly??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

C is pass by value, so any changes made to a parameter are local to the function.  If you want to change the value in the caller, you need to pass an address.  eg:

```
#include <stdio.h>

enum Color {red, green, blue};
char *colornames[] = { "red", "green", "blue" };

struct Book {
    int pages;
    char *author;
    char *title;
    enum Color color;
};

void
getInfo(struct Book *book)
{
    book->pages= 200;
    book->author = "Cervantes";
    book->title= "El Quijote";
    book->color = green;
};

void
showInfo(const struct Book *book)
{
    printf("pages: %d\n", book->pages);
    printf("author: %s\n", book->author);
    printf("title: %s\n", book->title);
    printf("color: %s\n", colornames[book->color]);
}

int
main(void)
{
    struct Book book1;

    getInfo(&book1);
    showInfo(&book1);

    return 0;
}
```